# calculation in SharePoint List(guess JavaScript Code required)

Tags: javascript

[Calculate the remaining budget in this SharePoint List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GcKI.png)

Hello, I will need to add a calculation on the top of list, as you can see from the screen shot, I will need to get the remaining budget by using the "total budget minus the sum of actual cost" column. Can you please kindly help me how to achieve this? I guess JavaScript code might help?
 thanks,

Comment: You could use a content editor webpart to access the list through REST API and display the calculated total.

Comment: You can get the sum of the values required by the loop to display at the top of the list

Comment: Hi Yang Shun, I'm not an expert on Rest API, can you give me more details?

Comment: Which Sharepoint version do you use?

Comment: I'm using SharePoint 2013, enterprise version